# Reflected Brownian motion on a compact interval whose lenght is going to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a Brownian motion $X_t$ in the interval $[0, \gamma]$ which is reflected at the boundaries $0$ and $\gamma$. We call $P_\gamma$ the law of such reflected Brownian motion.
The generator is defined on continuous functions $f:[0, \gamma]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f'(0)=f'(\gamma)=0$ in the following way

$$L_\gamma f(X)=\frac{1}{2}f''(X)$$
I would like to prove that

$$\lim_{\gamma\to 0}\mathbb E_{P_\gamma}(f''(X))=0.$$

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: As you let $\gamma\downarrow0$, what happens to $f$? If $f$ is fixed in the process, then we wouldn't have, in general, $f'(\gamma)=0$ for all $\gamma$ (except when $f=\text{const.}$). Does $f$ get deformed as well, as $\gamma\downarrow0$, in which case there should be an explicit functional form for $f$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the fact is that the domain of the generator is modified as $\gamma\to 0$, so the function $f$ should be deformed as $\gamma\to 0$.